# How to allocate the all my Ram memory usage to my system?

Tags: windows-7, memory

My laptop has 8 GiB RAM, but in system properties it is showing 2.45 GB usable. I am using windows 7 **32 bits**.

How I allocate all my memory to the system.some applications are not working properly.getting the memory error.

[image: system properties]

Comment: The most your system could use is just a little over 3GB.  Format your machine and install a 64-bit OS

Answer (score 3):

For sme reason you have installed a 32 bit OS (as show in your screenshot). Win 7 32 bits is limited to 4GiB **minus** address space reserved for other things like PCI-e address space etc.

This is normal and it is the reason why you should use a 64 bit OS. (aka, check your backups and doa clean installation with win7-x64 orany other 64 bits OS).

Also: I'll remove the hardware failure and system restore tags since they have nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: While I mostly agree with you, it is not the only reason to use 64bit windows. 64bit architecture actually has more CPU registers and other components that actually make the CPU faster, but those cannot be used in 32bit emulation mode. I personally benchmarked 64bit 7z compression to be 27% faster than 32bit.

Comment: It does have more accesible registers in 64 bit mode. The speed gain from that is not great but it indeed it present. It also used larger addresses, so more memory/cache is used, On average this tend to cause no significant speed gain or significant speed loss. Individual application may differ ofc.